# Binding to DataGridColumn using ReactiveUI C# based Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, reactiveui

I am learning to use ReactiveUI in WPF. I have an application that has an IObservableCollection which I am binding to a DataGrid.

```
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" x:Name="validationResults" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Cell">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Id" x:Name="vrContractID"  Binding="{Binding Path=ItemId, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item #"  Binding="{Binding Path=ItemNumber, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50"/>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Valid?" Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="5"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Error Code"  Binding="{Binding Path=ErrorCode, Mode=OneWay}" MinWidth="50"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Error Message"  Binding="{Binding Path=ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay}" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I'm trying not to use XAML based binding like I have showed you above however, I'm having issues understanding how to accomplish this style of binding in the code behind file using something like:

```
this.Bind()
```

Or this:

```
this.OneWayBind()
```

I've had similar issues binding DataTemplates and MultiBinding and this makes me wonder if there is something I'm missing about the design pattern for ReactiveUI/MVVM.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS: If I must bind this using xaml binding - why wouldn't I just do all my binding in xaml? It sort of feels weird to have 2 places where binding can occur.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with DataTemplates is to not set one and the rxui binding will automatically provide one and look for registered `IViewFor<TViewModel>` registered for the view model and show that view.

Multi binding you can use `Observable.CombineLatest` with multiple `WhenAny` operators and then use `BindTo`.

With data grid the story is you can programmatically generate the columns then use rxui binding on those. In the past I have used a builder pattern for it. The DataGrid out of the box isn't really easy to combine with rxui binding.

Comment: If the DataGrid is not great for RxUI, can you explain why and provide an alternative approach? I choose datagrid because I wanted to display a list of items in a grid format and allow users to take advantage of the built int sorting. It is also the first control that comes to mind when thinking of displaying results in a grid. I am not using the grid in edit mode so I wonder if there is a better display oriented control.